# How bad is it to take another year for my undergraduate degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, canada

Complex analysis (or more particularly contour integrals) is kicking me downhill (again), and I may need to drop it (again). If I do, I would only have to take a single course in my 5th undergraduate math degree, another 3rd year math course like complex analysis (3rd times a charm???). If I don't drop it, I risk getting a low enough GPA to not get into graduate school. I already applied. So how bad is taking another year?

Did anyone else do this? How many of you were able to get into graduate school even after taking another year? Is there a bias? What are the pros versus the cons?

People have mentioned this to me before in the past, like it was inevitable, but I never really considered it until now. When I ask others if they would do it, they act like it's unthinkable for them. Like they are inherently better than me so course they wouldn't need to do this.

Comment: Is this the US? Will you get good letters of recommendation? Any chance for some research opportunity in the fifth year?

Comment: @Buffy,  I don't know? Could you expand on research opportunities? I feel like I'm not fully sure what that is or how to guarantee such a thing. Would having a fifth year help with this?

Comment: I was a terrible undergraduate student.  It took me nearly a decade to finish my BA.  I've got a phd now.  Taking some extra time to finish a degree is not a career ending decision.  Poor grades as an undergraduate are not career ending.  However, these things can make life more difficult, particularly if the problems you encounter are towards the *end* of your bachelor's work, rather than at the beginning.

Comment: Xander, Libor: please do not write answers in comments. Comments are for requesting clarification on the question, or suggesting improvements to the post itself (e.g., better tags). More details [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short). Your answers do seem valuable; please consider moving them to the answer box.

Comment: There are biases, your professors will (hopefully) know more specifics and can help, but I really don’t think there is anything wrong with taking an extra year. The people who act like its unthinkable have a narrow mindset. I was one of them. At the graduate level it is very typical to spend an extra year even after your thesis is “finished” polishing it and giving yourself a better chance on the job market. The same should be true in undergrad (although finances, among other things, are different).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a really good relationship with one (or more) of your math profs then you could make  a fifth year work to your advantage. Ask them what research opportunities you have with them, perhaps as an independent study. If you could put together a nice, but do-able, project to fill up the rest of the time for the additional year, then it could work out to be a plus.

But this assumes, for purposes of graduate study, that your GPA is good enough and you have some insight into one or more math subfields. You don't need (nor is it possible to have) universal insight, but something with which you can be clearly predicted to be a success by letter writers.

You are in a difficult place, I think, but is may still be possible to recover through hard work and faculty contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Your future grades have zero impact on the outcome of graduate school applications made in the past.  You say you have already applied, so most likely your question is not related to achieving the outcome you want.

You probably do need to complete the bachelor's degree to start the graduate degree.  Any admissions offers you receive may be rescinded if your final grades are too low, but I have never heard of an offer being rescinded, and some universities will not actually check those grades.

Once you have a graduate degree, it is unlikely that anyone will care how long your undergraduate degree took.  If your undergraduate degree overlapped the pandemic, then taking longer to finish will not be remarkable.

Meeting the minimum standards for graduate school is not a good goal for your undergraduate studies.  I suggest you make a longer term plan for your career.  Graduate school is not a career, and not all graduate degrees are actually helpful.